# How to initialize a const field in constructor in typescript?

Tags: javascript, class, typescript, constants

I don't know if theres even a value in this.  I'm just curious if it is possible?

### **Question:**

if it's possible and what are the syntax for

**initializing a const field in constructor in typescript?`**

```
export class Gulpfile {
  private dist: string;
  private src: string;

  constructor(){
    const this.dist = './dist/';
    this.src = './src'
  }
 }
```

Comment: You should try Gulpfile.dist = './dist/' instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have a constant class member.

Mainly because class members are always referenced by reference via the **this** keyword, and that reference can always be changed.

It's not supported in ES6 either.